# Admobs test rewarded ads only load twice in Android build made with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I have built a game for Android with Unity. I use Admobs test Google Ads right now and they load perfectly fine for the first two levels. After that, rewarded ads will not load anymore. Banner and interstitial ads still work fine. If I close and restart the application, the ads work twice again. I included a screenshot of the Logcat error message, displayed when the ads fail to load. Any idea why this could be happening?

First time posting here so I hope I did this right.

[Error displayed in Android Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRo4n.png)

Here is the code I use:

```
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

namespace SortIt.Ads
{
    public class RewardedAdManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Action RewardedAdClosed;

        [SerializeField] private bool preLoad = default;

        private bool isAdLoaded;
        private RewardedAd rewardedAd;

        public void ShowRewardedAd ()
        {
            Debug.Log ("SHOW REWARDED AD");

            if (rewardedAd.IsLoaded ())
            {
                rewardedAd.Show ();
                isAdLoaded = false;
                StartCoroutine (CreateAndLoadRewardedAd ());
            }
        }

        public bool IsAdLoaded ()
        {
            return isAdLoaded;
        }

        private void Awake ()
        {
            if (preLoad)
            {
                Debug.Log ("PRELOAD ADS");
                StartCoroutine (CreateAndLoadRewardedAd ());
            }
        }

        public IEnumerator CreateAndLoadRewardedAd ()
        {
            Debug.Log ($"ARE ADS LOADED {GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript.AdsReady}");

            while (!GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript.AdsReady)
                yield return null;

            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";

            rewardedAd = new RewardedAd (adUnitId);

            rewardedAd.OnAdLoaded += HandleRewardedAdLoaded;
            rewardedAd.OnAdClosed += HandleRewardedAdClosed;
            rewardedAd.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleAdFailedToLoad;

            AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder ().Build ();
            rewardedAd.LoadAd (request);
        }

        private void HandleAdFailedToLoad (object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            var rewardedAd = sender as RewardedAd;

            rewardedAd.OnAdLoaded -= HandleRewardedAdLoaded;
            rewardedAd.OnAdClosed -= HandleRewardedAdClosed;

            isAdLoaded = false;
        }

        public void HandleRewardedAdClosed (object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            var rewardedAd = sender as RewardedAd;

            rewardedAd.OnAdClosed -= HandleRewardedAdClosed;

            RewardedAdClosed?.Invoke ();
        }

        public void HandleRewardedAdLoaded (object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            var rewardedAd = sender as RewardedAd;

            rewardedAd.OnAdLoaded -= HandleRewardedAdLoaded;

            isAdLoaded = true;
            Debug.Log ("REWARDED AD LOADED");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for loading Ads?

Comment: Edited the question to include the code that I use for the rewarded ads.